# c reading character one by one from a file?

Tags: c

Say I have a file like so:

```
1234
56e8
1245
```

Is there a way I could read one character at a time and perform operations on them? Or, is there a way I can read a line and extract each character from it?

I've been trying to use `strtok` and use delimiter but can't seem to find a delimiter that can do the job.

Comment: So you want a `f`ile-`get`-`s`tring function, if only such a thing existed, and was called something rather intuitive like `fgets`. Before you learn to program, learn to use google, please

Comment: possible duplicate of ["while( !feof( file ) )" is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. An easy way to read cha racter by character would be to use `fgetc`:

```
int c;
FILE *fp = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
   printf("Error opening file!\n");
   return -1;
}

while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
  // Character is read in `c`
  // Do something with it
}

fclose(fp);
```

As for reading line by line, use `fgets`:

```
char line[100];
FILE *fp = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
  printf("Error opening file!\n");
  return -1;
}

while (fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL) /* Reads a line */
{
  // One line is stored in `line`
  // Do something with it
}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: When you answer a question you should indent your code properly.

Comment: @MichaelWalz ,Isn't it indented? Maybe my (old) phone isn't displaying it properly!

Comment: I just edited your answer. Now it is indented. You see the difference ?

Comment: Correct formatting of your code is very important, otherwise it's unreadable and very hard to understand and to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use strtok if you want to examine every char.

There are many tutorials on this.
This code will read one character at a time.

```
FILE * pFile;
int c;
pFile=fopen ("myfile.txt","r");
if (pFile==NULL) 
    perror ("Error opening file");
else
{
    do {
       c = fgetc (pFile);
    } while (c != EOF);
}
fclose (pFile);
```